# CDK dashboard metric with functionName

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

I'm logging metrics from an AWS lambda. When I go to CloudWatch console I can see these metrics listed under my lambda function. I can manually create graphs with these metrics, they will be listed as

Namespace: xxx
Metric name: yyy
Function name: zzz
Region: region

I would like to programatically create dashboards with these metrics. Unfortunately, [as per the CDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.Metric.html), the `Metric` class doesn't contain a `functionName` field. So the best I can do is

```
new Metric({
   namespace: 'xxx',
   metric: 'yyy',
   statistic: 'Sum'
})
```

This will create a graph which has no data, because it cannot find the metric.

I also tried using a `MathExpression` with an expression like `SELECT SUM(..., FunctionName) WHERE FunctionName = 'zzz'` and this does work, but unfortunately a MathExpression can only query a 3 hour period, while I need it to work with much larger time scales.

Anyone knows how can I create a Metric which uses a metric from a function? The same way how I can create it manually from AWS Console? Is there perhaps a special class for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I need to provide the functionName as a dimension. This works:

```
new Metric({
   namespace: 'xxx',
   metricName: 'yyy',
   statistic: 'Sum',
   dimensionsMap: {
     FunctionName: 'zzz'
   }
})
```